# How can I create an empty global class and instantiate it upon startup?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, encapsulation

I’m building an Arduino project and would like to build a reusable library.  However what I can easily do in C# is eluding me in the C/C++ syntax the Arduino firmware uses.

I would like to instantiate a global instance of class **Foo** that also contains a structure  **Bar** which will be used in the constructor of **Foo** so I can take advantage of encapsulation, e.g. if I need to add a new element to **Bar** I can do so easily.

C#

```
Foo myFoo;

void BobBobLaw()
{
    Bar myBar = new Bar();
    myBar.A = 1;
    myBar.B = 2;
    myBar.C = 3;
    myFoo = new Foo(myBar);
    myFoo.DoSomething();
}
```

How can I accomplish something similar for the Arduino platform?  BTW, I chose to use a struct instead of a class for **Bar** because that information is immutable and should be private.  I’m not sure if this is the correct choice, but I read a few posts that said this is the “preferred” way to do things.

Comment: What is `Foo`? What is `Bar`? Why are you using `new`?

Comment: `struct` _does_ declare a class, and doesn't make anything "immutable" or "private" any more than a class does.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: you can use of `static` member class, because you can access to them when program run in memory without creating instance

Comment: As I said, this is C# syntax, so you use **new** to create a new instance of an object.  Foo is a class, Bar is a structure

Comment: I think you’re missing the point of ther question.  I’d like to be able to create a global class variable, and instantiate it in a startup class.  In the Arduino, this would be the **setup** sub.

Comment: Your requirement does not make any sense in C++. Either the object exists or it doesn't. You can't "initialise it later". You'd have to have a global pointer and later dynamically allocate, but that's really not something you want to do. There's a reason I'm trying to steer you away from the C#, and that's because C++ and C# are sufficiently different that thinking in C# will never yield the right answer.

Comment: So how would I be able to create an instance of a class if I don't know until runtime what the parameters of **Bar** would be?  Just create the class and pass in **Bar** later?  Multiple constructors?

Comment: Use `std::optional`.

Answer (score 1):

As `@Lightness Races in Orbit` mentioned in the comments. You can declare pointer to a Foo in global context and in the setUp function you can initialize in the global pointer with new'd object of Foo.

Using `struct` doesn't make it Bar immutable. In C++, structure is equivalent to a class just with an exception of default access specifier being public. One way to make Bar immutable is to make members private and make sure only the constructor can modify it.

Following example gives one such example with immutable Bar as member of Foo class. I hope you find it useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Bar {
private:
    int A,B,C;
public:
    Bar(int a,int b, int c):A(a),B(b),C(c){};

    int getA() const { return A; }
    int getB() const { return B; }
    int getC() const { return C; }

};

class Foo {
private:
    Bar *mBar;
public:
    Foo(Bar barInstance) {
        mBar = new Bar(barInstance.getA(),barInstance.getB(),barInstance.getC());
    }
    void DoSomething() {
        std::cout<<"Doing something";
    }
};

Foo *fooPointer;

void setUpArduino() {
    Bar myBar(1,2,3);
    fooPointer = new Foo(myBar);
    fooPointer->DoSomething();
}

int main() {
    setUpArduino();
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm starting to understand what's going on when he meant (it either exists or it does not). This looks very helpful.  I'll try it out later tonight.